# digital root recurion without using loop and digitsum

Tags: c++, recursion, function-definition

Iam trying to solve this recursion question below which is apparently asking to find digitaroot without using loop or digitsum.It is possible?

{The digital root of an integer n is defined as the result of summing the digits repeatedly until only a single digit remains.  For example, the digital root of 1729
can be calculated using the following steps:
Step 1: 1 + 7 + 2 + 9
→
19
Step 2: 1 + 9
→
10
Step 3: 1 + 0
→

Because the total at the end of step 3 is the single digit 1, that value is the digital
root.
Write a function
DigitalRoot(n) that returns the digital root of its argument.
Although it is easy to implement DigitalRoot using the DigitSum function from
exercise 6 and a while loop, part of the challenge of this problem is to write the function recursively without using any explicit loop constructs.}

Answer (score 2):

Catch!:)

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned int digital_root( unsigned int x )
{
    if ( x < 10 ) return x;

    x = x % 10 + digital_root( x / 10 );

    return x < 10 ? x : digital_root( x ); 
}

int main(void) 
{
    std::cout << digital_root( 1729 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << digital_root( 1917 ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1
9
```

Or you can rewrite the return statement of the function the following way

```
unsigned int digital_root( unsigned int x )
{
    if ( x < 10 ) return x;

    x = x % 10 + digital_root( x / 10 );

    return digital_root( x ); 
}
```

Or the function can look even like this

```
unsigned int digital_root( unsigned int x )
{
    return x < 10 ? x : digital_root( x % 10 + digital_root( x / 10 ) ); 
}
```

Comment: for `x > 10` you are checking `x < 10` twice consecutively, you should change the return statment to `return digital_root( x );`

Comment: @dlavila It is not important.

Comment: I know, but it is not efficient

Comment: @dlavila  I think that it is without the second check it is not efficient because it calls itself one more when there is already clear that the number is less than 10.

Comment: depends on the input, if you have 100 recursive calls, you'll have to do 99 extra comparisons with the first version. Assuming that the inputs are homogeneously distributed among all the `unsigned int` values, the second version is best in avarage.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should split the number first (taking n % 10 and n / 10, and apply the recursion on the second side.

The problem then is apply it to the result. The key for writing your recursive function is keep in mind that must return (without sub calls) only when the incoming parameter is < 10.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can rework the code from python: this worked on several testcases

```
def digitalSum(n):
  if n < 10:
      return n
  else:
      return (n%10 + digitalSum(n//10))

def digitalRoot(n):
   if digitalSum(n) > 9:
      return digitalRoot(digitalSum(n))
   else:
      return digitalSum(n)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int  getsum(int num) {
    if(num==0)
        return 0;
    return getsum(num - 1) % 9 + 1;
}
```